# ARTrackedImageManager does not contain definition to CreateRuntimeLibrary()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5zCN.png)

```
library = ARTrackedImageManager.CreateRuntimeLibrary();
```

So I'm trying to create a runtime image library and it doesn't find the definition to the method. I have imported all the needed libraries and looked for solutions everywhere but I can't find any solution.
What could be the issue?

Comment: Are your `using` statements correct? Can you post the entire code?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: I update the plugins in package manager.